# How to get the return type of a boost::signal?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, boost-signals

I use `boost::signal` with different function signatures and different combiners.
In a class that looks like the one beyond I want to get the return of a certain signal declaration.

```
template<typename signal_type> class MyClass
{

    signal_type mSignal;

    signal_type::result_type getResult() { return mSignal(); }

}
```

But `signal_type::result_type` does not work. So is there a way to get the return type?

Comment: Its always a good idea to post the error you are having.

Comment: I don't follow, signal_type::result_type is the return type, what doesn't work?

Comment: @Konrad: see the link i commented in the accepted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `typename` to use dependent types:

```
typename signal_type::result_type getResult() { return mSignal(); }
```

Dependent names (i.e. dependent on a template parameter) are assumed to

- not name types unless prefixed with `typename` and to
- not name templates unless immediately prefixed with `template`.